# What is the difference between Kubernetes Engine and Container Engine and why the latter one does not appear on my dashboard?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

Sorry for the dumb question I'm new to cloud computing.

I'm trying to do [this](https://medium.com/google-cloud/how-to-create-google-container-engine-gke-using-the-google-cloud-platform-console-925dd1cc9400) tutorial and I've listened to [this](https://youtu.be/g0dN8Hkh5H8?list=PLfa0JnnntRviUWOHSofUusCbaEe6u2MDX&t=1298) video of Google Next.

According the linked tutorials I should see two different menu items on my dashboard, but only Kubernetes Engine appears on mine.
I can't figure out what's the reason of not seeing the Container Engine menu item.

As I understand, the Kubernetes engine should be a managed container engine (managed by Google) and the Container Engine is unmanaged. 
If I want to experiment with Docker Swarm or with Apache Mesos, the Kubernetes engine is not good for me. If I type 'Container Engine' into search field, the Kubernetes Engine comes up.

Questions:
Why is this menu item visible on video and in tutorials, and it's not visible on my dashboard? What happened to this menu item?
Was this funcionality removed from google cloud? Or was this functionality somehow merged into Kubernetes Engine?

Comment: Google Container Engine has been renamed to Google Kubernetes Engine in Nov 2017, the abbreviation GKE remains unchanged. https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2017/11/introducing-Certified-Kubernetes-and-Google-Kubernetes-Engine.html

Answer (score 7):

Google Container Engine is **renamed** as Google Kubernetes Engine. It’s the same product.

https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2017/11/introducing-Certified-Kubernetes-and-Google-Kubernetes-Engine.html

The tutorial and the video you linked are created before the rename has happened, and therefore they’re probably not going to reflect the name change.